# .htaccess blocks images from mobile site aka root/mobile

Tags: javascript, php, image, .htaccess

I been researching countless topics regarding accessing images when a user is logged into a mobile site. I'll try to explain everything to the point and any help is super appreciated.

I have website (root/index.html) and a mobile version redirected to (root/mobile/index.html) via .htaccess

I have all my subscribers individual folder accounts as followed: (root/1234567, root/1122334, root/9876543, etc..) with their uploaded images inside (root/1234567/image1.png, etc...)

When a user logs into mobile via (root/mobile/login.php) and tries to view an image via JavaScript www.mysite.com/1234567/image1.png it "breaks".

I tried all suggestions in my research, however when I delete .htaccess from root it works so I know the root .htaccess file is the culprit but I do need security on subscribers folders (root/1234567 etc...) but allow access on image files within subsribers folders. I can post both .htaccess files contents of root and root/mobile

Here's my root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 
"android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile|opera 
mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!mobile/).*)$ /mobile [L,R=301]

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|txt)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 403 https://www.mysupersite.com/
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mysupersite.com/

Options -Indexes
```

And my root/mobile .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysupersite.com/mobile [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 
"!android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|ipad|iemobile|opera 
mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysupersite.com [L,R=301]

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|txt)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 403 https://www.mysupersite.com/mobile
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mysupersite.com/mobile

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Looks like you are rewriting _all_ requests to `/mobile`, when a matching UA is set. So when `www.mysite.com/1234567/image1.png` gets requested by a mobile device, you redirect that request to `www.mysite.com/mobile`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I will be editing my question soon. I had to bypass any filenames ending with jpg png or gif with a rewrite rule. Thanks again.